# Proving increasing and bounded

Tags: analysis

Suppose {$a_n$} is a bounded sequence. For $b_n = \inf\{a_k: k \geq n\}$, prove that $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is increasing and bounded.

I was thinking of using the definition of lim inf where when  $b_n = \inf\{a_k: k \geq n\}$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\inf a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}\inf b_n$ and since it has an infimum then it then by definition bounded.

For proving it increases, I was thinking about using induction.

Is this a good approach? If not how would I go about proving this.

Comment: Contradiction on the increasing?

Comment: HInt: If $B$ is bounded and $A$ is nonempty subset of $B$ then $$\inf B\leq \inf A.$$

Comment: @Jan Are you sure that there is a contradiction on the increasing?

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Yes. What I meant "suppose, towards a contradiction, that $b_{n}$ is decreasing". Maybe I was not clear enough. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: @Jan Ah okay, I got what you mean, I thought that you are in doubt if it is increasing. I misinterpret your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$, write $$A_n=\{a_k:k\geq n\}.$$ Then, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $$A_{n+1}\subset A_n.$$ Thus, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, we get (with the hint I posted in the comment)
$$b_n=\inf A_n\leq \inf A_{n+1}=b_{n+1}.$$
This proves that the sequence $\{b_n\}$ is increasing.

For boundedness of the sequence  $\{b_n\}$, let us observe the following:

Since $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots\}$ is bounded, we can find two real numbers $m,M$ such that 
$$m\leq a_i\leq M$$ for all $i\in\Bbb N$. This implies that for each $n\in\Bbb N$, we have $$m\leq b_n\leq M.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $A,B$ are bounded sets of real numbers. If $A \subset B$ then
$$\inf B \le \inf A.$$
Why? Suppose that this isn't true, i.e that
$$\inf B > \inf A.$$
Then, there exists $x \in A$ such that $x < b$ for all $b \in B$. But $A \subset B$ and so $x \in B$ (and $x$ is not strictly less than itself). This is a contradiction!