# Suppose {$x_n$} is a bounded sequence. Defind $a_n$ and $b_n$ as in Definition 2.3.1. Show that {$a_n$} and {$b_n$} are bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose {$x_n$} is a bounded sequence. Defind $a_n$ and $b_n$ as in Definition 2.3.1. Show that {$a_n$} and {$b_n$} are bounded.

[image]

no idea to solve this question..

Comment: Try to see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168348/proving-increasing-and-bounded/2168382#2168382). Maybe that can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x_n$ is a bounded (by this, we mean above and below) sequence, the sequence $\{x_k : k \geq n\}$ is subsequence of $x_n$, hence is also bounded. Therefore, if we define $a_n = \sup \{x_k : k \geq n\}$, then this sequence exists and is bounded. Furthermore, if $n \geq m$, then we see that $a_n \leq a_m$, as the size over the set in which we are taking supremum has become smaller.

Now, $a_n$ is a sequence, which is bounded and decreasing. Hence, it follows that $a_n$ is a convergent sequence (tell me if you don't know how  this follows, but first try an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument yourself).

Similarly, the sequence $b_n$ will also be convergent, because it will be bounded and increasing (because we are taking infimum,  not supremum here).

Hence, not only are $a_n,b_n$ bounded, but the associated limits also exist (and are called limit superior and limit inferior respectively).

EDIT:

In response to comment, we first need a candidate for the limit. Since $a_n$ is decreasing and bounded, we take the candidate for the limit as $L = \inf a_n$.

Now, pick $\epsilon > 0$. We know that by definition of infimum, $L+\epsilon$ is not a lower bound, so there exists $N$ such that $a_N < L+\epsilon$. However, because $a_n$ is decreasing, $m > N \implies a_m \leq a_N < L + \epsilon$. By definition of limit convergence, we get the limit as $L$.

You can do a similar thing for $b_n$, but the candidate limit will be $\sup b_n$, since the $b_n$ are increasing.

Comment: can you express more about (tell me if you don't know how this follows, but first try an ϵ−δ argument yourself) this part.. ?

Comment: Ok, I will edit my answer.

Comment: so To prove $a_n$ and $b_n$ is bouded, you are showing that $x_k$ is subsequence of $x_n$. so I don't have to prove if sequence is bounded, its subseuqnece is bounded ?

Comment: I know that it is obvious that if seuqnece is bounded, its subsequence is also bounded, but my professor is so strict :/

Comment: Your professor is strict, that is indeed unfortunate. As far as I am concerned, this step is obvious to me. If it is trivial to you, then I have done my job (It surely is obvious to you, is it not?)

Comment: It is so obvious to me. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome!